# How to organize the config files and dlls generated by the msi installer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installation

I have created a project in `C#.NET`, which **3 config files and 2 dlls**.  For creating setup, I am using `Visual Studio Installer(Setup Project)`.  I would like to organize my primary output as follows:

1. Separate folder for config files and dlls.  I tried below in the image but after installing the application is not running.
   [image: Structure]

Answer (score 0):

The dlls you referenced and the default configs for your assembly must be in the same folder as the executable. You cannot just put them where you want them.

If you load those dll assemblies yourself and load those configs yourself in your assembly, you are free to put them where you want. But that's probably not worth the amount of time you'd have to put into it.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please explain about loading dll assemblies and config files by myself?